# Apply function to all the elements (lists of strings) of a column to convert into floats

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda, apply

My dataframe df has a column 'c' of lists of strings. For example the first element is `df.loc['index_0','c'] = ['10', ' 20']`.

I want to convert all the elements in the lists into floats. For example the first element of df should be `df.loc['index_0','c'] = [10.0, 20.0]`.

I know how to do it for one list at a time using `list(map(float, df.loc['index_0','c']))`.

I would like to do it for all the lists and I tried this: `df['c'].apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x)))` but I get an error: *'float' object is not iterable*

Comment: I tried it with your code and it works!

Comment: Try to make sure that all values of df['c'] are lists not a float number. If you iterate through float number, you will get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is due to the presence of `NaN` values in the column `c`, one way to fix this is to remove the NaN values before applying the map function:

```
df['c'] = df['c'].dropna().apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works for the lists of strings after I discard the NaN values. However, it fails for some floats that are also present. I would like to cast those floats into lists of one single element so that I can then apply your solution successfully. How do I do that? Having lists of floats across the board is necessary for other work I am doing with the resulting dataframe and functions that iterate through lists.

Comment: @ric You can do something like this: `df['c'].dropna().map(lambda x: [*map(float, x)] if isinstance(x, list) else [float(x)])`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['C'].apply(lambda x: [float(element) for element in x])
```

This works if I understood correctly